# Views page redirect to current page with parameter

Tags: 8

in drupal 7, I use `drupal_goto` function for the redirection. I'm trying a few methods in d8, but couldn't make it work.

If I visited a certain page for example `/views-page-example`, I would like to redirect users to the same page, but with parameters. Once visited, the users should be redirected to `/views-page-example?name=value`. I'm using `template_preprocess_page` to trigger the redirection.

This is the current code I have so far:-

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();

  if ($current_path == '/views-page-example') {
    $path = "/views-page-example?name=value";
    $route_name = url::fromRoute($path);
    $response = new RedirectResponse($route_name->toString());
    $response->send();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't send a response in custom code. Use an event subscriber to set the response, so that it can be returned by Drupal:

*mymodule.services.yml:*

```
services:
  mymodule.event_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\MymoduleSubscriber
    tags:
      - {name: event_subscriber}
```

*src/EventSubscriber/MymoduleSubscriber.php:*

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class MymoduleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  public function checkForRedirection(RequestEvent $event) {
    if ($event->getRequest()->query->get('redirect-me')) {
      $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse('http://example.com/'));
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['checkForRedirection'];
    return $events;
  }

}
```

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/2013014

---

Example to check the current path and that the query parameter is not present yet:

```
public function checkForRedirection(RequestEvent $event) {
  $request = $event->getRequest();
  if ($request->getPathInfo() == '/example' && !$request->query->has('name')) {
    ...
```

Comment: cool.. how can I call it a specific page?

Comment: should I call it in THEME_preprocess_page? then which method from src/EventSubscriber/MymoduleSubscriber.php should I call? \Drupal::service('mymodule.event_subscriber')->checkForRedirection() ?

Comment: No, preprocess was wrong in D7, too. The correct place was hook_init and this is in D8 an event subscriber, see the DO link. The code in this event subscriber is only an example. You can put your code checking for the current path in there.

Comment: I see. To which method can I check the current path? Trying to debug in getSubscribedEvents, but my log isn't showing.

Comment: The code from your question should work, a shorter version would be `$current_path = $event->getRequest()->getPathInfo();`, btw you might need to check for the query parameter too, to stop a redirect loop.

Comment: Could u pls edit your answer and specify where can I add `$current_path = $event->getRequest()->getPathInfo()` trying to add them on both methods, but looks like it's not being called

Comment: cool.. thanks for your answer. it's working now :)